# $wpdb->prepare syntax confusion

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Struggling to see why this isn't returning anything - pretty sure it's a syntax mistake on my part (there are definitely rows in the wp_rg_lead_detail table with field_number of 2 and value of Trys)

```
function manageGetSearchEntries( $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $fullQuery = "SELECT * FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE (%s, %s) = (%d, %s)";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $fullQuery, $query[0], $query[1], $query[2], $query[3] ), ARRAY_A );
    return $result;
}

$entryData = manageGetSearchEntries( array( 'field_number', 'value', 2, 'Trys' ) );
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Probably you are trying to pass non access key `$query[4]` it should be `$query[3]`

Comment: @RahilWazir That was my bad when setting up the question, $query[3] fails to bring anything back either. I've updated the question - sorry about that.

Comment: @trysmudford Whats the output of `var_dump($entryData)`?

Comment: What is `WHERE (%s, %s) = (%d, %s)` supposed to mean?  That's not valid SQL.

Comment: I think it is now working - but I'm not 100% why... When I move `$query[0]` and `$query[1]` into the `$fullQuery` string in place of the %s, the call returns correctly.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I also thought that its invalid sql syntax but what you say about this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/24938

Comment: @RahilWazir: Maybe it's being interpreted as a Point or something?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Hmm yup. We don't have to put quotes `"` around column names. As `%s` convert variable as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not valid SQL. It should be more like

```
WHERE (%s = %d) AND (%s = %s)
```

Comment: So is the correct SQL? `$fullQuery = "SELECT * FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE ($query[0] = %s) AND ($query[1] = %s)";` It runs correctly, but it would be nice to know if it's the right way.

Comment: `%s` = string, `%d` = integer. if your'e passing in the wrong things, then your query won't work no matter how much sql fiddling you do.

Comment: @trysmudford Your SQL Syntax is valid. And this should work just fine => `$fullQuery = "SELECT * FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE ($query[0], $query[1]) = (%d, %s)";`

Comment: @RahilWazir: uh, no, it won't be fine. that's still an outright syntax error. `('foo', 'bar') = ('foo', 'bar')` is not going to work in **ANY** sql db.

Comment: @MarcB `WHERE ('foo' = 'bar') AND ('foo' = 'bar')` this also won't work.

Comment: yes it will. it's syntactically valid. it'll evaluate to a boolean false, but it will WORK. Your version is a flat-out syntax error and will NEVER work, period.